# Why does security belong in the SOAP header instead of the SOAP body?

Tags: security, soap

I can easily create a base class for all my messages that contain a username and password that the user sets for each request.  The user could also add this in the SOAP header.  Does it matter and why?

Comment: Depending on what framework you're using, you  may be able to use a common class to put this into the header.

Comment: It's not "security" so much as "sensitive data". Session cookies and passwords are sensitive data *by definition*; they really shouldn't appear in logs/debug output. Stripping headers (either all headers or "known-sensitive" headers) is much easier to do reliably than parsing and re-serializing XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the header is meant for "out of band" information. Information that is not so much about the current message, as it is about the *fact* that you're sending messages.

To the extent that security information isn't changing from one message you're sending to another, that information should not be in the individual message bodies, but should rather be in headers that get sent with *every* message body.

Another thing is that headers can be used for information which changes when the same message body can be sent to different destinations, each of which may have its own requirements for headers.